# How can the TCP socket creation class gets notified that one new peer is added to the registry?

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp, hashmap, p2p

I am implementing a P2P service. The idea is using UDP to search for peers and build it's own registry. And using TCP to do the real communication.
I want to create one more new TCP socket connection, if there's one more peer added to this peer's registry. The registry is implemented in hashmap .
How can the TCP socket creation class gets notified that one new peer is added to the registry?

Comment: Just call a method in your TCP class when you add a peer to the registry? I don't understand what your problem is.

Answer (score 3):

Simply implement a class like 'TcpConnectionManager' which registers itself with the registry - lets call it 'P2PConnectionRegistry' at startup. (The registry has to be a class maintaining a HashMap - it cannot be a HashMap.).

If a new connection has to be created, you call p2pConnRegistry.addConnection(...); from somewhere (e.g. UI).

This method adds the required params it's internal data structure (e.g. the HashMap) - and then calls registryListener.connectionAdded(...);
This registryListener is a instance of TcpConnectionManager.

This is a very simple model for "seperation of concerns".

I hope this was your question it it helps, greetings,
Michael